# open vs2013 project in vs2015 port already in use

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

I have recently moved from VS 2013 to VS 2015. I created a new MVC project and it Worked fine. Then I opened an existing project and run it. It give following error.[image]

I opened `applicationhost.config` to change port but there is no such configuration like it was in VS 2013. Is that configuration moved to another file? How to change port and how to tackle this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the project and click on properties, Then on the left click on web, under project URL you can change the port. click save, it will ask if you want to create the new virtual directory for the port.

Comment: It worked. but in VS 2013 I was working on subdomains and have configuration in applicationhost.config like `<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:abc.localhost" />` and `<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:def.localhost" />` How to achieve this configuration in VS 2015.

Comment: With the new ASP.NET tooling, your custom IIS web server configurations are stored in the solution’s .vs folder in an applicationHost.config file. This should help isolate your web server configurations for each of your projects without conflicting references to a single configuration file.

Comment: Thanks! So the answer is simply `C:\Users\Irfan\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication1\.vs\config\applicationhost.config`

Comment: Yes depends on where you set your default folder up. And now that file has most all the IIS settings so you dont have to go back and forth.

Comment: This option doesn't appear for me; either clicking properties page/window on project, or properties on solution, there is no 'web' option where it used to be in older versions of VS. Is it just hidden for me?

Comment: This must be a startup project type of MVC or Windows Forms, in order for the Web tab to be visible.